# Kernel of a morphism between coherent sheaves.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Throughout this book, http://books.google.co.kr/books/about/Algebraic_Geometry_and_Arithmetic_Curves.html?id=uaLKdA0PxS4C&redir_esc=y, kernel of a morphism between coherent sheaves on a locally Noetherian scheme is also coherent.

More precisely, let $X$ be a locally Noetherian scheme and  $u:\mathcal{F}\to\mathcal{G}$ be a morphism of coherent sheaves on $X$. Then $\textrm{Ker }u$ is also coherent.

The author says, this is trivially true. However, I cannot prove it. Moreover, I do not know whether it is really true or not.

Even though I do not have any explicit example, I think this would be false in following sense; when $X$ is locally Noetherian scheme and $\mathcal{F}$ is a coherent sheaf on $X$, it is known that $\mathcal{F}(U)$ is finitely generated $\mathcal{O}_X(U)$-module for any affine open subset $U$ of $X$. If $\textrm{Ker }u$ is coherent, then the sequence $\textrm{Ker }u(U)\to\mathcal{F}(U)\to\mathcal{G}(U)$ of $\mathcal{O}_X(U)$-modules is an exact for any affine open $U$. However, in general, a submodule of a finitely generated module is not finitely generated. So, maybe there would be an example that arises form the sequence $\textrm{ker} f \to L\xrightarrow{f}M$ where $L,M$ are finitely generated modules and $\textrm{ker }f$ cannot be generated by any finite set. Is this reasonable?

Actually, we can find the same statement for $X$ is Noetherian case in Hartshorne's book. If the above statement is true, how can we expand the case?

Comment: The kernel of a morphism between coherent sheaves on a scheme  is always coherent, and local noetherianness of the scheme is irrelevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $X$ is locally noetherian, and since submodules of f.g. modules over a noetherian ring are finitely generated, we can see that this is locally true: that is for any affine open spec$R$, there is a cover $U_i=D(f_i)$ of Spec$R$, $f_i\in R$ generating the unit ideal, such that ker$(f)(U_i)$ is finitely generated.

Thus, all we have to prove is the following gluing result: Let $f_1,...,f_k$ generate the ideal $(1)$ in a ring $R$. Let $M$ be a module on $R$. We want to show that if $M_{f_i}$ are all finitely generated $R_{f_i}$-modules, then $M$ is a finitely generated $R$-module. Indeed, let $\frac{m_{ij}}{1}$ generate $M_{f_i}$, where $m_{ij}\in M$.

Let $m\in M$. By our assumption, we can fix a number $N$ and elements $r_{ij}\in R$ such that

$f_i^Nm=\sum_j f_i^Nr_{ij}m_{ij}$ for all $i$.

But now we use the fact that $(f_1,...,f_r)=1$, so we may write $1=\sum_{i=1}^k s_if_i$, $s_i\in R$. Taking this equation to the $kN$th power, we see that, in fact $(f_1^N,...,f_r^N)=(1)$ as well.

Thus we may write $1$ as a linear combination of the $f_i^N$, so we may write $m$ as a linear combination of the elements $f_i^Nm$, which, by our earlier equation, means we can write $m$ as a linear combination of the $m_{ij}$.

So the $m_{ij}$ generate $M$ and we have proven $M$ is finitely generated.

Comment: You don't need all this since coherence is defined locally. What you prove (and of course can also be found everywhere) is that $M$ is of finite type iff $\tilde{M}$ is of finite type.

Comment: I assumed by the nature of the question that their difficulty was going from local to global, but I might be wrong

Answer (score 3):

Hint: A ring $R$ is noetherian iff submodules of f.g. $R$-modules are again f.g.

Comment: Since it's only locally Noetherian, don't we have to do a bit more work and show that the property of being finitely generated glues?

Comment: No, recall the definition of coherent.